# passing a variable as a parameter to varchar() as in cast(column1 as varchar(@variable))

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, parameters, casting

Using SQL Server 2014. As a challenge someone asked me to return 113.05 as 0.05 in a select statement.

I put forth the following:

```
declare @temp1 table (value1 numeric(5,2))
insert into @temp1 (value1)
values
(113.05);

select value1, cast('.' + right(cast(value1 as varchar(6)), 2) as numeric(3,2))
from @temp1;
```

which works, but then i thought what if there are multiple rows in value1 and all have different lengths other than 6. How can i pass the length of value1 as a parameter as in cast(value1 as varchar(length of value1)?

i have tried declaring a variable @length and setting it to equal len(value1) and then passing it as varchar(@length) but that won't work. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: If you are just looking for the values after the decimal, then you could cast to a varchar and then get the charIndex of the decimal point.  Then return your substring based on that index + 1 to the length of the cast value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't do this like that at all. Use math, specifically MODULO.

```
declare @temp1 table (value1 numeric(5,2))
insert into @temp1 (value1)
values
(113.05)
, (911.123)
, (1.22)
, (.3)

select value1
    , UsingMath = value1 % 1
from @temp1;
```